# Beginner trouble with Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using Rails 3.2.

I'm trying to make a form that allows the user to input the Colleges that they want to compare, and the criteria for which they want to see compared. Here's my code. When I submit the form, it redirects back to the page, but doesn't display the parameters in the h1 tags. What's wrong?

**Controller**

```
class ComparisonController < ApplicationController
  def view
    @summaries = Summary.all
    @colleges = College.all
  end

  def update
    @college_listing = params[:comparison][:college]
    @summary_listing = params[:comparison][:section]
    redirect_to '/comparison', college_listing: "#{@college_listing}", summary_listing: "#{@summary_listing}", notice: 'Showing comparison.'
  end
end
```

**View**

```
<%= simple_form_for :comparison, :url => '/comparison/update' do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :college, collection: ['University of Pittsburgh', 'University of Wisconsin - Madison', 'Colgate', 'Adelphi'], :input_html => { :multiple => true } %>
    <%= f.input :section, collection: ['Professors', 'Classes', 'Difficulty', 'Campus', 'Food', 'Dorms', 'Safety', 'Social Atmosphere', 'Parties', 'Actuarial Science', 'Agriculture', 'Applied Math', 'Astronomy', 'Biology', 'Chemistry', 'Computer Science', 'Earth Science', 'Geology', 'Linguistics', 'Mathematics', 'Neuroscience', 'Physics', 'Statistics', 'Anthropology', 'Criminology', 'Economics', 'History', 'Political Science', 'Psychology', 'Sociology', 'Urban Studies', 'Women\'s Studies', 'Art', 'Classics', 'English', 'Film', 'History and Philosophy of Science', 'Literature', 'Music', 'Philosophy', 'Religious Studies', 'Theatre', 'African', 'Chinese', 'French', 'German', 'Italian', 'Japanese', 'Jewish', 'Latin American', 'Middle Eastern', 'Russian', 'Spanish', 'Other', 'Accounting', 'Finance', 'Management', 'Marketing', 'Bioengineering', 'Chemical', 'Civil', 'Computer', 'Electrical', 'Engineering Science', 'Industrial', 'Materials Science and Engineering', 'Mechanical', 'Nuclear', 'Architecture', 'Athletic Training', 'Communications/Journalism', 'Information Science', 'Nursing', 'Nutrition', 'Pharmacy', 'Public Health', 'Rehab Science', 'Social Work'], :input_html => { :multiple => true } %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>

<h1><%= params[:college_listing] %></h1>

<h1><%= params[:summary_listing] %></h1>
```

Comment: I have lol. I did Michael Hartl's, One Month Rails, and the learn-rails tutorials. Still struggling though :/

Comment: I don't get it. When I submit the form, it goes to the update action. Then I have to redirect back to the view action with the variables available. How do I make them available? The view action doesn't have access to the submitted form parameters, so the only way I could think of is via typical url parameters.

Comment: @mbratch I tried `<h1><%= @college_listing %></h1>
<h1><%= @summary_listing %></h1>` in the view, but it didn't work. Are you saying that all instance variables in a controller are available to all the controllers actions?

Comment: Could you please explain "didn't work"? Did you get an error, or just not the data you expected?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48738/discussion-between-adam-zerner-and-mbratch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your controller:

```
def update
    @college_listing = params[:comparison][:college]
    @summary_listing = params[:comparison][:section]
    flash[:notice] = 'Showing comparison'
    redirect_to :controller => 'comparison', :action => 'view', :college_listing => @college_listing, :summary_listing => @summary_listing   
end
```

As to why it wasn't working before -

`redirect_to` has the following signature:

```
def redirect_to(options = {}, response_status = {})
```

When you call it with the string for url it sets the options hash to be the string you've passed in and everything after that becomes the response_status and is not appended to the url as `get` params.

If you wish to pass the flash notice in the redirect_to call, then you better off calling a named route (run `rake routes` to find what the route to  `comparison#view` - it is probably just `comparison_url'. You would then formulate your call like this:

```
redirect_to comparison_url(:college_listing => @college_listing, :summary_listing => @summary_listing ), :notice => 'Showing comparison'
```

Calling comparison_url with your params in parethesis will create the correct `get` request for Rails to redirect to - in this case, you are actually passing a proc in to redirect_to.

The Rails code is not all that intimidating to dive in to if you fancy - here's `redirect_to` https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb

The various ways Rails responds when you call redirect_to boils down to the private method `_compute_redirect_to_location`

Comment: That worked, thanks! For my knowledge (I'm trying to learn), could you explain what went wrong, and why it wasn't working before? The other guy was helping me and we tried some foo tests, and the parameters from the `redirect_to` weren't being passed along.

Comment: also, the `:notice` isn't working after I added `<% if flash[:notice] %>
    <div id="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
<% end %>`. Do you know why?

Comment: Updated my answer - sorry the original `notice` was wrong - it should work now. Hope the explanation makes sense as well

Comment: Thanks, that works now and makes more sense. So why did you have to call the named route in order to pass in `:notice`? Is it because `:notice` is part of the `response_status`? What exactly is `response_status`?

Comment: You don't have to call the named route to get :notice to work. You can do `redirect_to '/comparison', :notice => 'foo'`. However when you want to pass variables, calling the named route (actually a method) allows you to pass params into the named route method which generates the get request with params attached. Then you can pass the flash params as well. If you pass a string as the route then everything after that is eventually put into the response_status, thus your flash will come through, but variables will be discarded. `response_status` is for http status like 404 not founds etc